# How to separate dates in wrapped cell by line break?

Tags: excel, vba

I have comment data in column A:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

I'm trying to loop through cells in col A and separate the comment to look like what you see in col B (line break every time a date appears Instr).

Here's the code I tried, but it ran through and didn't do anything. I figure I'm sort of on my way to getting it working, but this wasn't an easy problem to research online as I haven't seen other posts attempting this.

Code I tried to piece together to get an idea:

```
Sub Line_Breaks()

Dim c As Range
Dim searchstring As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
searchstring = Format(Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value, "m/d/yyyy")

    For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
            If InStr(1, c.Value, searchstring) Then
                c.Value = Split(c.Value, vbNewLine)
            End If
        
    Next c
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `separate the comment to look like what you see in col B` Please show Col B in your screenshot.

Comment: @taller I actually just redid the screenshots because I want the updated formatting to occur in column A where the comments are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `RegExp` pattern matchs the desired string, but the code does NOT validate if it is a valide date. eg. 99/99/99 will be considered as a matched string.
- The code writes the ouput to Col B. You can modify it to update Col A.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, oSht As Worksheet, sTxt As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = oSht.Cells(oSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With objRegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})"
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            sTxt = Trim(oSht.Cells(i, 1))
            If .Test(sTxt) Then
                sTxt = .Replace(sTxt, Chr(10) & "$1")
                If Left(sTxt, 1) = Chr(10) Then sTxt = Mid(sTxt, 2)
                oSht.Cells(i, 2) = sTxt
                ' Update Col A
'                oSht.Cells(i, 1) = sTxt
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Came up with the exact same solution - you beat me by some minutes. Just a hint: Use `vbLf` rather than `Chr(10)`

Comment: @FunThomas May I know the difference between `vbLf` and `Chr(10)` in this case? Thanks

Comment: No difference except better readability.